# import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset; is not visible in the module

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

i am not able to import defaultcategorydataset in my program

import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset; is not visible in the module
.. I imported  category dataset instead of defaultcategorydataset but still it is not working

Comment: If required, [JFreeChart v2.0.0](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart), not yet released, is _modular_.